# How does Spark load ordered parquet partitioned files with order?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After I sorted all the entries and use `write()` function to S3, I want to re-load the data with exactly the same order and same partitions.

I tried to use `read()` and `load()` function but none of these work. Do we have a way to load the partitioned parquet files with same order and partitions?

Comment: Parallel processing is inhibited by ordering. And harder to optimize.

Comment: I agree with @thebluephantom above, however I know spark is way more sequential in its IO than you would expect for what it does and is supposed to be. With that said, a quick question: are you using partitionby when writing then basepath option when reading or...?

Answer (score 0):

if read() and load() did not help i would suggest to read file names from S3 and order it in fashion you need and then read back those files in the order in the spark. You can always build up your DataFrame (if you are and keep adding data to it from these partitions that you just read)